# How can I set the window type of a WindowedApplication to be lightweight in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

How to do it using spark? Because it says it can't find "window".

([similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950571/how-can-i-set-window-application-as-light-weight-in-flex-still-not-get-answe))

Answer (score 2):

Window is an AIR only class.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Window.html

http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/components/Window.html

So, the way you do this in Flex 4 is the exact same way you do it in Flex 3; but you'll have to be developing an AIR application not a browser based application.

If you were more specific issues; please expand and perhaps share some code.

Comment: well, what I'm doing is inserting this:

var window:BlankWindow = new BlankWindow();
window.type = NativeWindowType.LIGHTWEIGHT;
window.open(true);

an I resieve debugging error that "window" does not exist...
that's in Flex 4 SDK, If I change it to SDK 3, then there will be no error, that's shy I'm asking how to do it in the new sdk with "s" tags instead of "mx"

Comment: Add a runnable example to your original question and I'll take a look.